# Parameterized class that keeps Bokeh x and y range

Tags: python, bokeh, panel

I have a parameterized class that calls and updates a class of bokeh plot objects using @pn.depends. Unfortunately this means that when I launch the server and update widgets the bokeh x-y range gets reset. I have looked over the prior exampels using hvplot and hv.DynamicMap and unfortunately hv.DynamicMap does not like taking a param object. I would prefer not to use the holoviews bokeh extension for 1) the simple reason that I’ve already coded things up and have this one sticky issue and 2) I like being able to not have to call a df directly in the plot line, such that it is simple to read how things are getting plotted (at least for me). Minimum reproducible example below.

```
import pandas as pd
import bokeh
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure
import panel as pn
import param

data = {'x': np.random.rand(10),'y1': np.random.rand(10),'y2': np.random.rand(10), 'y3': np.random.rand(10)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
color_palette = bokeh.palettes.Muted9

class plots():
    def __init__(self,*args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        for a in args:
            self.__setattr__(str(a), args[0])
    
    def line_plot(data,ys_to_plot,vert_line1,vert_line2):
        fig = figure(height=500,width=500,tools='pan,reset,save,wheel_zoom,xwheel_zoom,ywheel_zoom')
        
        for v,c in zip(ys_to_plot,color_palette):
            fig.line(data['x'],data[v],line_width=0.7,legend_label='{}'.format(v),color=c)
        
        fig.line([vert_line1,vert_line1],[0,1],line_width=0.4,line_dash='dashed',color='black')
        fig.line([vert_line2,vert_line2],[0,1],line_width=0.4,line_dash='solid',color='black')
        
        return fig
    

class update_plots(param.Parameterized):
    ys_to_plot = param.ListSelector(default=['y1'], objects=['y1','y2','y3'])
    vert_line1 = param.Number(default=0.2,bounds=(0,1))
    vert_line2 = param.Number(default=0.8,bounds=(0,1))
    
    def __init__(self,**params):
        super().__init__(**params)
        self.widgets = pn.Param(self,parameters=['ys_to_plot','vert_line1','vert_line2'])
        
        
    @pn.depends('ys_to_plot','vert_line1','vert_line2')
    def dynamic_plot(self):
        return plots.line_plot(df,self.ys_to_plot,self.vert_line1,self.vert_line2)

callapp = update_plots(name='my application')

widgets = {'ys_to_plot': pn.widgets.CheckBoxGroup}

vanilla_layout = pn.template.VanillaTemplate(title='my application',
                                             sidebar=pn.Column(pn.WidgetBox(pn.Param(callapp.param,widgets=widgets))),
                                             sidebar_width=380)
vanilla_layout.main.append(pn.Row(callapp.dynamic_plot))      
vanilla_layout.show();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!